# ActiveRecord find records in intervals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to execute some code to every user in my database. For this I created a script and run it with `rails runner myscript.rb`

```
User.all.each do |user|
  # code on user
end
```

If I have 500 user in my database this works but if I have for example 4000 users I get some errors given some of the code inside the `.each` given the amount of users. (This numbers are fictional)

For this reason I want to execute this script in intervals of 500 users.

How can I execute every 500 users until there are no more users?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each):

> Looping through a collection of records from the database (using the `Scoping::Named::ClassMethods.all` method, for example) is very inefficient since it will try to instantiate all the objects at once.
>
> In that case, batch processing methods allow you to work with the records in batches, thereby greatly reducing memory consumption.

You want to say:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  # code on user
end
```

That will load the users 1000 at a time and hand them one by one to your "code on user" block. You can specify different chunk sizes if you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it under while do loop and the user object can be set to `User.all.sample`. By doing this, until there are no users left, your script will work then quit. But you should add a flag to your table.

Let's imagine that you are trying to send e-mail to all users, and you should have a field to use as flag similar to `email_sent`.

And now your user object is `User.all.where(email_sent: true).sample`

---

Another aproach may be using querying jobs by user. Create a loop thorugh your users and have the index of the loop. Set index*amount_of_time seconds to start the query. So in case you have 1000 users and you set index*2 seconds of buffer in between users. It will take 2000 secs. to handle all jobs queried.

---

There are another solutions. If you can better explain what you are looking for and what practise you need; I can suggest you a better one.